# how to extract a specific value from an XML file, the value after the XML tag; (ex.after = sign?)

Tags: linux, grep, xml

I have a file which has  `ReferenceId="0128140321960O"` and also `RelatedReferenceId="SWCC"`

```
<FinancialTransfersInstruction xmlns="middleware.frk.com/Schemas/Onetis/1.0">
<SWIFTHeader DeliveryMethod="SWIFT" MessageType="202" OrigSendDate="2019-11-15" Receiver="SBOSUS3UIMS" ReferenceId="0207060050180O" Sender="TESTBIC" SenderName="TEST INVESTORS, INC" TransType="NEW"/>
<PortalHeader BusinessUnit="GTS"/> <Wires> <Wire Currency="USD" Id="20706s5018.0" RelatedReferenceId="CCPM" </Wire> </Wires>
<FinancialTransfersInstruction/></FinancialTransfersInstruction>
```

When I run my command to extract the value, my result gives me related reference too; I only want the ReferenceId tag value.

```
cat *.xml |grep -P -o -e '(?<=ReferenceId=").*?(?=")'
```

Comment: `grep -P -o -e '^ReferenceId=\K.*' file.xml` (`\K` means Forget everything till now)

Comment: hi Thank you for the quick response, unfortunately  it doesn't return a value.

Comment: Please add a full line example that contains the text of interest.

Comment: Hi i'm a doing this on redhat linux 7.  to reproduce this please create a text file  with the following line it,

Comment: The XML that you have posted in a comment should be added to the question. Also, that XML seems to be severely broken and can't be parsed by an XML parser.

Comment: I'll second that - please provide a valid XML snippet in your question

Comment: i know its broked, unfortuantely i cant paste the  entire xml here.

Comment: @Nightfly you don't necessarily need to provide the entire XML. The outermost element (which includes valid `xmlns` declararations) and some valid XML would be a good start. You might also want to explain if `<SWIFTHeader/>` is a singleton element or one of a repeating set - and if a repeating set, from which one of the set you want the attribute value extracted.

Answer (score 2):

The XML in your question is invalid. Assuming your corrected XML is actually this,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FinancialTransfersInstruction xmlns="https://middleware.frk.com/Schemas/Onetis/1.0">
  <SWIFTHeader DeliveryMethod="SWIFT" MessageType="202" OrigSendDate="2019-11-15" Receiver="SBOSUS3UIMS" ReferenceId="0207060050180O" Sender="TESTBIC" SenderName="TEST INVESTORS, INC" TransType="NEW"/>
  <PortalHeader BusinessUnit="GTS"/>
  <Wires>
    <Wire Currency="USD" Id="20706s5018.0" RelatedReferenceId="CCPM"/>
  </Wires>
</FinancialTransfersInstruction>
```

you can use `xmlstarlet` to parse the XML and to extract the appropriate attribute value

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:SWIFTHeader/@ReferenceId' bankfile.xml
0207060050180O
```